# How to configure Google ads data hub account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-ads-data-hub

How to get an access to Google Ads Data Hub (ADH).
https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub

Answer (score 1):

To configure or set up an Ads Data Hub account you’ll need to:

1. Structure your Ads Data Hub account.
2. Configure your Google Cloud project(s): Designate an admin project.
3. Enable the API on your admin    project.
4. Create a BigQuery dataset.
5. Permission Ads Data Hub to write to your Google Cloud project.
6. Provision user access.
7. Link data to your Ads Data Hub account.

For video based guidance or for more information you can refer to - https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/account-setup

Answer (score -1):

You need to have it enabled by your Google reps. You have to contact them first, as per the ads data hub homepage.